# Angular6 Submit form of iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, angular2-forms, form-submit, angular6

I have to use an iframe (heidelpay creditcard service) inside my angular component. This iframe bascily is just a form but it doesn't have a submit button.

I need a way to submit this form via a button once the user puts in his creditcard informations into the iframe. I would like to solve this by providing an button in my own html component.

This is what i have:

```
<ion-content>
  <iframe #form class="screen-top-spacing" *ngIf="heidelpayUrl" [src]="heidelpayUrl | safe"></iframe>
  <ion-button (click)="submitIframe()">Click</button>
</ion-content>
```

So my question is how my submitIframe() function needs to look like.

Note: The form inside the iframe has an id (paymentFrameForm)